# Initializing LiveData from lateinit object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following code

```
lateinit var roomdb:RoomDb

val penLiveData:LiveData<Pen> = roomdb.getPen()
val paperLiveData:LiveData<Paper> = roomdb.getPaper()
val rulerLiveData:LiveData<Ruler> = roomdb.getRuler()
...
```

As you might expect I am getting an exception that roomdb was not initialized. How do I fix this without too much complication? And please in your response take into account that I have multiple liveData fields that depend on `roomdb` and I don't want to have to do a bunch of work for each one of them.

`roomdb` is necessarily initialized by a method call, not inside `init`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with `Transformations.switchMap.

It feels a bit like someone just asked why the gun pointing at their foot doesn't fire. This is me telling you that the safety is still on, what you do to your foot is your business.

Basically, you have a LiveData that will kick of the other's to fetch/refresh.

```
private val _loadData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val penLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(_loadData) { roomdb.getPen() }
//...
```

Then you set `_loadData.value = true` after ensuring that `roomdb` is set.

Maybe the following is a little cleaner?

```
private val _loadData = MutableLiveData<RoomDb>()
val penLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(_loadData) { it?.getPen() }
//...
```

and

```
_loadData.value = roomdb
```

or, if within an asynchronous context.

```
_loadData.postValue(roomdb)
```

You probably want to return some Default or NullObject (like AbsentLiveData from AAC samples) if `switchMap` parameter is `null`.